# Consider creating a separate tag for Fortnite's "Battle Royale" mode

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[fortnite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortnite) has an entirely distinct [Battle Royale game mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortnite_Battle_Royale) (PvP, Save the World is PvE),  which is sometimes referred as a standalone title, with its own progression system and game mechanics. It may be beneficial segregate the modes to avoid confusion and help users finding advice for their preferred version.

[image: Battle Royale mode menu screenshot]

During "early access" the Battle Royale mode is free-to-play while Save the World campaign is paid.

Comment: I would be in favor. Even though both are accessible from the same client, they both play quite differently and have different mechanics (projectile dropoff, different weapons, different items and stats, etc). Plus it's led to confusion on [at least other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/320706/145980) (\*cough\* mine \*cough\*) before.

Comment: There are currently less than 50 questions for the tag, it is less work to fix the existing questions early on. As far as I see there may not be any other game with so rapidly increasing playerbase.

Comment: Do we do this for any other games? This is the same game, so it should have one tag. We don't make separate tags for Hearthstone-Arena / Hearthstone-Solo-Adventures / Hearthstone-Ranked...etc

Comment: @FoxMcCloud: Hearthstone apparently uses the same cards and rules in all modes. See Mage Xy's comment above for Fortnite differences. What is your definition for another game? If Battle Royale solely was a separate program on PC and console, would you accept this request?

Comment: @FoxMcCloud: Team Fortress 2 and Diablo 3 classes have their tags, Grand Theft Auto Online is separate from GTA V while being mode in the game and Minecraft has own tags *even for single user-created mods*. Are you aware of this?

Comment: (I do not necessarily endorse own tags for game classes —  only used as example)

Comment: @user598527 TF2 and D3 were created years ago and we've talked about how they are mistakes. We're not going to add 40+ tags for Street Fighter like we did for D3. In the case for Minecraft, they are literally different games. Different mechanics, objectives, items, worlds, servers...Minecraft is a special case. MOST games are not special, it's just PvE VS PvP. What we can add are synonyms, so anyone searching for just one will be redirected to the correct tag.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud I would definitely say that Fortnite and FortniteBR are fundamentally different games. They happen to use the same graphics and similar mechanics, but the game itself is totally separate.

Comment: Think of it like the difference between Zelda: Ocarina of Time and Zelda: Majora's Mask. Same graphics, even lots of the same gameplay, but very obviously distinct.

Comment: @MageXy No, I think they are two different modes that you can play with the same game. The game itself is not totally separate, you can play both modes if you buy the game. I'm not sure I understand your Zelda example, we have two tags for those games, we didn't combine them. My example would be Call of Duty's zombie mode. We do not create new tags for zombie mode with new CoD games, because it's the same game, just a different way to play.

Comment: I think GTAV / GTAO is a reasonably strong point of argument. A counterpoint might be LoL with Rift / Treeline / ARAM -- they have slight differences (items; global passives). Anyway, I think these discussions should actually be happening in answers and not the question itself.

Comment: Just throwing in my two cents: I think there's a bit of difference between "sub-tags" like Diablo's or TF2, where the tag is used *in conjunction* with the main game tag (useful for sorting & searching purposes), and "standalone game mode" tags like GTAV vs GTA:O - where the entities are considered effectively separate games and the tags *shouldn't* be used together. I  don't know enough about Fortnite but if it's split similar to GTAV vs GTA:O I'd be in favour

Comment: Maybe make a *battle-royale* tag and use it in conjunction with Fortnite and other games that provide this game mode? Fortnite will probably not be the last game with a BR mode.

Comment: @dly - No, we moved well away from general game genre/mode tags early on for a lot of reasons. For one, they're inconsistently applied, requiring a lot of manual effort to make sure the tag gets used consistently. It's also of little benefit, being an 'expert' in one battle royale game doesn't make you an expert in another, just like being an expert in CoD doesn't mean you're an expert in TF2, despite both being "first-person-shooters".

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Based on the feedback from the Arqade community, I've gone and burninated [fortnite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortnite). Questions are now tagged with either [fortnite-battle-royale](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortnite-battle-royale) (*41*) or [fortnite-save-the-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortnite-save-the-world) (*23*).

---

I'm in favor of separate tags for [fortnite-battle-royale](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortnite-battle-royale) and  [fortnite-save-the-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortnite-save-the-world).

**Despite sharing a title, both modes have little in common.**

- Fortnite: Battle Royale

  - Free to play
  - Supports up to 100 players in competitive multiplayer
  - Available on PC, PS4, Xbox One, iOS, and Android
  - Progression does not carry over to PvE mode
- Fortnite: Save The World

  - [Costs $39.99](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/fortnite-standard-founders-pack/bxwnx8st04js)
  - Supports up to 4 players in online co-op
  - Available on PC, PS4, and Xbox One
  - Progression does not carry over to PvP mode

**Questions are usually about one mode or the other.**

- [Is there a way to practice with weapons and buildings in Fortnite: Battle Royale?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/330458/181240)
- [How can I see my ping in Fortnite BR?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/330007/181240)
- [How to tell if a Save The World mission will have a "major storm incoming"?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/327751/181240)
- [Do Battle Royale item spawns rely on location?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/320688/181240)

**Both games have separate communities.**

- [US Gamer - Fortnite's Pivot to Battle Royale Has Split the Community in Two](https://www.usgamer.net/articles/the-fortnite-community-is-divided)
- [PC Gamer - How Fortnite PvE fans feel about Battle Royale taking over the game they love](https://www.pcgamer.com/how-fortnite-pve-fans-feel-about-battle-royale-taking-over-the-game-they-love/)
- Separate subreddits  [r/FORTnITE](https://www.reddit.com/r/FORTnITE/) and [r/FortNiteBR](https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/)

**There is precedent for separating tags for games with distinct game modes:**

- [grand-theft-auto-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5) vs [grand-theft-auto-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-online)
- [metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain) vs [metal-gear-solid-5-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-online)

Since a majority of the current questions seem to be about Battle Royale, I suggest manually retagging questions about [fortnite-save-the-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortnite-save-the-world), then retagging the rest as [fortnite-battle-royale](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortnite-battle-royale).

The relatively few small number of questions that ask about both modes can use both tags.

Comment: You probably could have spread out the edits a bit more...

Comment: @JMac My apologies for flooding the front page. It slipped my mind while editing.

Comment: Hi @Steven - I cleaned up the 'update' section to only describe the final state of the tag rename - should make it easier on future readers to understand what exactly was done. If people want the full history, they can view the [revisions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/12982/revisions) directly

Comment: @Robotnik Agreed, the new version is easier to read. Thanks for the update.